# Calculating outdegree of a node in Graph

Tags: c++

I have implemented following code for Graph. For calculating the outdegree of any node outDegree funcion is there. It will take the name of the node, whose outDegree need to be calculated. I was wondering that in calculating the outDegree of any node, can I use find() function provided in vector. If yes, how ?

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<iterator>
    #include<vector>
    #include<list>
    using namespace std;
    template<class T1,class T2>
    class Edge{
            public:
            T1 d_vertex;
            T2 d_weight;
            Edge(T1,T2);
            T1 vertex();
            T2 weight();
    };
    template<class T1,class T2>
    Edge<T1,T2>::Edge(T1 v,T2 w):d_vertex(v),d_weight(w){
    }
    template<class T1,class T2>
    T1 Edge<T1,T2>:: vertex(){
            return d_vertex;
    }
    template<class T1,class T2>
    T2 Edge<T1,T2>::weight(){
            return d_weight;
    }
    template<class T,class T2>
    class Graph{
            vector<pair<T, list<T2> > > node;
            public:
            void addNode(T data,const list<T2>&);
            void show();
            int outDegree(T);
    };
   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    template<class T,class T2>
    int Graph<T,T2>::outDegree(T node_name){
            for(int i=0;i<node.size();i++){
                    if(node[i].first==node_name)
                            break;
  }
        if(i==node.size())
                return -1;
        else
        return(node[i].second.size());
}
template<class T,class T2>
void Graph<T,T2>:: addNode(T data, const list<T2>& lst){
        node.push_back(pair<T, list<T2> >(data,lst));
}
template<class T,class T2>
void Graph<T,T2>:: show(){
        for(int i=0;i<node.size();i++){
                cout<<node[i].first<<"------ ";
                for(typename list<T2> :: iterator it=node[i].second.begin();it!=node[i].second.end();it++)
                        cout<<(*it).d_vertex<<" ";
                cout<<endl;
        }
}
int main(){
        Graph<int,Edge<int,float> > g;
        list<Edge<int,float> > x;
        x.push_back(Edge<int,float>(4,float(3.5)));
        x.push_back(Edge<int,float>(5,float(4.0)));
        g.addNode(3,x);
        list<Edge<int,float> > y;
        y.push_back(Edge<int,float>(4,float(6.3)));
        y.push_back(Edge<int,float>(2,float(12.0)));
        y.push_back(Edge<int,float>(1,float(2.1)));
        g.addNode(6,y);
        g.show();
        cout<<g.outDegree(6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you use C++11 you could use find_if with a lambda:

```
#include <algorithm>

template<class T,class T2>
int Graph<T,T2>::outDegree(T node_name)
{
  typename vector<pair<T, list<T2> > >::const_iterator it
    = std::find_if(node.begin(), node.end(),
                   [&node_name](const pair<T, list<T2> > &n) 
                   {
                     return n.first ==node_name;
                   });

  if(it != node.end())
    return it->second.size();

  return -1;
}
```

As a sidebar: If you want to work with graphs productively, use lemon (http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon) or something similar.

Comment: Will using find_if will be more efficient then what I had done in my code ?

Comment: Nope, in the worst case it will have to step through each vertex... If you use a `std::map<T, pair<T, T2> >` you can get it down to log size, a hash map might be even faster