# Define "visited" variable for a node in a graph

Tags: c++

I have written the code for graph that you can see on following link.

[Calculating outdegree of a node in Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426684/calculating-outdegree-of-a-node-in-graph)

Now, I need to write BFS and DFS for the same. For that I need to have a variable "visited" to define whether the node is visited or not. I realised that I will have to include this variable in the

```
class Graph{

vector<pair<pair<**bool**,T>, list<T2> > > node;

}
```

Here bool is the condition whether the node is visited or not. For this I had to do the changes in the entire code. Is there any other way, where I can include the variable without doing much modification in the code ?

Ok, I got it. Its quite simple. Sorry to ask such a question. I can define another

```
vector<bool> visited
```

in the BFS function. I will update the code after writing the function. Once again sorry.

Comment: You should write a class `Node` for which you can simply add a bool 'visited'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing marker of visiting inside class is not good idea - because you can do it only once - after that you have to reset everything before starting algorithm second time. As an alternative you have 2 options:

- Instead of `bool` use some number - that unique identifies number of algorithm was applied, so before test if node of visited you have to increase **global apply counter** and check if version of node strictly less than **global apply counter**.
- You can declare hash-map (for c++11 use [unordered_map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/) ) that tracks IDs of node (as a not good, but workable example use pointer to node). So if id of node is exists inside hash-map than node was visited. After algorithm was applied just destroy the map

I'd prefer second case.

p.s. And yes, comment of @a_guest - is correct - create your class Node